What does the Church of England's doctrine say about issues of sexual identity and practice?
Like almost all churches, the Church of England and even more the wider Anglican Communion is struggling to come to terms with the vocal and growing minority of, in their own terms, "non-heteronormative" people, within the church as well as within the wider society. This concerns gender-fluidity/changes as well as homosexuality. The issue is contentious within and between the congregations.
This question is motivated by another question: What should an Anglican priest do who cannot in good conscience represent the more libertarian stance of their church regarding the fairly broad complex of sexual identity, gender fluidity, homosexuality etc. In one specific case cited, a priest was put on leave after opposing in a sermon what he perceived as LGBT indoctrination bordering on coercion by a sexual education charity at a primary school.
The OP of that question perceived a mismatch between the more conservative official doctrine of the Church as opposed to their more libertarian actions. The question claimed that the priest was "upholding the Church of England’s doctrinal stance".
I tried to find out what that official stance might be. There is a long Wikipedia page about the wider Anglican community's struggle to deal with homosexuality, and it is clear that the factual opinion spectrum, even just on this relatively narrow topic, is very wide.
But what is the official doctrine? I read passages of the Book of Common Prayer, "a key source for its doctrine":

The ordination vow did not seem to contain anything that directly would compel a priest to oppose LGBT... advertising.
There is a enumerated list of relatives that must not marry; homosexuality is not mentioned there, most likely because it didn't cross anybody's mind.
The Form of Solemnization of Matrimony talks about man and woman respectively husband and wife throughout. Whether the absence of same-sex marriage is to be taken as a prohibition or whether it simply didn't cross anybody's mind is, I suppose, up to debate.

Is there more in the official, binding doctrine that would compel a priest to resist his superiors in LGBT... issues as a matter of doctrinal principle?

The trouble with this is that it is pointless looking to the Thirty Nine Articles or to The Book of Common Prayer because these have been abandoned and there now exists no structured creed for the Anglican Communion to follow. The Anglican Communion has deliberately spread its arms wide to invite all, embrace all, include all, within a vast diversity. Thus identity of the Anglican Communion can neither be located, examined, documented or defined. It is everywhere and it is anywhere. It is thus a  matter of opinion to try to state the 'Church of England's Doctrine' on any subject, whatsoever.

I found a 2014 article from an official Anglican website here that discusses 'Same-sex marriage, clergy and the canons'.  Part of it says this:
Canon C1 for the church’s order, unity and witness: “according to the ancient law and usage of this Church and Realm of England, the priests and deacons who have received authority to minister in any diocese owe canonical obedience in all things lawful and honest to the bishop of the same”.
Canon C26 and its requirement of a clergyperson that “at all times he shall be diligent to frame and fashion his life and that of his family according to the doctrine of Christ, and to make himself and them, as much as in him lies, wholesome examples and patterns to the flock of Christ”.
It appears that the root of the conflict is that marrying someone of the same sex is incompatible with and a contradiction of canon B30 that:

"The Church of England affirms, according to our Lord's teaching, that marriage is in its nature a union permanent and lifelong, for better for worse, till death them do part, of one man with one woman, to the exclusion of all others on either side, for the procreation and nurture of children, for the hallowing and right direction of the natural instincts and affections, and for the mutual society, help and comfort which the one ought to have of the other, both in prosperity and adversity.


If a woman chooses to marry and then describe herself as married to another woman, or a man does likewise in relation to another man, then those actions are not compatible with marriage being a union “of one man with one woman”.  Here, in contrast with the canons quoted above, is where there is disagreement.  Jeremy Pemberton, Andrew Cain and others believe this canon is wrong and they have acted in ways they know are incompatible with this canon."

NOTE: I was unable to access the links to the three canons mentioned in the above document, so I have simply had to quote what the document said.
I then went to a Church of England document published in 2023 here A response from the Bishops of the Church of England about identity, sexuality, relationships and marriage.

The Living in Love and Faith teaching and learning resources were commissioned by the bishops of the Church of England in 2017 and produced in 2020. They explore human identity, sexuality, relationships and marriage in the contexts of the Christian faith, changes in society, and disagreements in the church… The bishops have been studying the Scriptures, reflecting on the Church’s tradition, engaging with the resources, and listening to the churchwide responses. Their task has been to discern God’s voice about what this learning means for the Church of England. The outcomes of their discernment are described here…  In addition, the Pastoral Consultative Group will lead – together with others – the production of the new pastoral guidance described below and present it to the House of Bishops.

This particular aim of the Pastoral Consultative Group is noteworthy:

The advice will seek to be consistent across dioceses and reflect the doctrine and ecclesiastical law of the Church of England.

The paper also admits that:

In recent decades, many in UK society have negotiated, wrestled with, and come to accept a range of understandings of gender identity, as well as come to a better appreciation of trans, asexual and bisexual identities. However, there remains disquiet, and debates in wider society, as well as in the church, are often damaging and bitter.

The paper concludes:

Therefore, much work of grace and love remains to be done, not least in a better and richer understanding of trans, bisexual and asexual people and their rightful cherished place within the Church and society.

The entire thrust of the document appears to be focused on how priests should reflect on the understanding of Christian marriage (page 6), on blessings and on prayers (page 7).
On page 8 it says civil marriage is gender neutral but Holy Matrimony is only between male and female. There is an interesting section at the bottom of the page about sexual intimacy, and mentions that opposite sex couples "may have been sexually active before a service of dedication, thanksgiving or blessing". This part ends on page 9. It's all about "joy and thanksgiving for couples in civil partnerships or marriage".
Pages 10 to 13 are about the church's response to LGBTQI relationships and how to "support and advise on identity, relationships, sexuality and marriage."
Page 12 mentions "Conversion Therapy" but I couldn't make out if the Church of England has rejected the legal position of Government or if it has rejected conversion therapy.
Page 13 says (1) "guidance will begin with a biblical and theological reflection on the gift of prayer" and (2) and will reflect on how prayer "relates to community, self-awareness, learning, listening, disagreement, power and vulnerability and transformation".
The word "canon" did appear somewhere, but no specific canon or what is says.  Finally, the guidance will be completed in mid 2023.
Where the Church of England now stands on issues of sexual identity and practice I could not say.

After discussion with some who have family as ordained priests in the Church of England (C of E) I learned the following. This indicates that there's a back-to-front approach to this question which needs to be flagged up if any beneficial understanding is to result.
Let's suppose that the College of Bishops in the C of E want to make canon law that which never was canon law. They know they cannot yet get a majority vote to pass what they want to introduce, regarding certain sexual beliefs and practices. Unless or until they can, they risk going beyond their own bounds, which does not authorize them to discipline priests who cannot conscientiously agree with those new standards.
The Bible states that certain sexual views and practices are to be eschewed (e.g. fornication and adultery) and this has long been a theological understanding in the C of E, even if many clergy and laity have taken a questionable stance / interpretation of what the Bible states here. But regarding sexual identity and practice that we may suppose some Bishops are now trying to establish in the C of E, the Bible nowhere says those things are to be believed or practiced. And this may be why some Bishops are seeing some priests as being such a 'problem' that they appear to be either threatening sanctions or actually castigating them, seeking to with-hold their salary.
This of course, will be stoutly denied by some, and claims that none of this can be proven will be made. Hence the need for legal agencies to come to the defense of priests under such pressure, or actual punitive measures. This is happening already in England and needs to be openly faced up to. Really, where there is no actual canon law to be appealed to here (and it may be that there is none), the only hope that Bishops have who might want to make acceptable the new views and practices with a view to enforcing action against clergy who disagree, is to obtain a majority vote. There are ways of doing that in systems where majority vote is taken as the supreme authority.
Opinions will continue to abound, which is why this sort of topic can hardly hope to obtain authoritative sources to settle it, when the supreme source of authority for the C of E ought to be the Bible. The way canon law presently stands, it appears that new laws need to be introduced to overcome objections from those who hold to the supreme authority of the Bible, but who have broken none of their ordination vows while objecting.
See https://freespeechunion.org/justin-welby-plainly-wrong-over-egregious-blacklisting-of-gender-critical-chaplain/  The Christian Institute http://www.the.ci/CriticalTheoryLT and http://www.the.ci/ChallengingTruth or watch their videos http://www.the.ci/CriticalTheoryWatch See also article by Aaron Prelock, Pastor of St Giles Mission, London, 'A new and rising Liberalism', http://www.reformation21.org

The Bible as the supreme authority is principally the correct approach. The problem is that the Christian denominations, even though they usually share a large part of the text, differ substantially in the canonical laws they derive from it (if any). That is one reason why I didn't quote the Bible in my text: The question here is what the C of E makes of it.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  My two spelling errors corrected; thank you for spotting them. Yes, a problem is differing views of what the Bible states on such matters, resulting in differing canon law, or no such law. That is why I did not quote the Bible in my answer. What does the C of E make of it? As, "A right dog's dinner" is merely my opinion, it needs to be C of E members who respond to that. But given that I have no vested interest, my answer has some validity.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Exactly my own point in comment, that it is impossible to tell what the Anglican Hierarchy (whoever, exactly, that is, for it could be that the Spouses of the Vicarage have more real power than the Incumbents of the Parish) from one month to the next. The gradual weeding out of Dumb Dogs that did not bark (when they definitely should have done so) will - possibly - leave a more distinctive Leadership. But I doubt it.

Up-voted +1. What is the use of supposed 'Bishops' which role never appears in the early Church, the episcopos being chosen within the assembly (out of the local eldership) and appointed by (only) those who Minister the word ? When Ministry is absent, there can be no episcopos. Thence is there no leadership. And the congregation gathers to no purpose. But 'the show must go ; please give generously'.
